# Analog clock with same hands - sometimes one can't tell time

Tags: modular-arithmetic, contest-math, systems-of-equations

There is an accurate analog clock, however both hands are the same size and shape.

How many moments during a day a person can not conclude current time from the position of the hands?

This is from a competition, I was told it is *a difficult problem*.

Comment: With "needles", do you mean the hands?

Comment: is hand the right word? @celtschk

Comment: If you mean the moving things which point to the digits on the clock face then hand is the right word.

Comment: @celtschk yes, i corrected it

Comment: I just notice: If taken literally, at *all* moments the current time cannot be inferred from the position of the hands, since you cannot tell from the hands whether it is am or pm. ;-)

Comment: hehe ok what i wrote was the original formulation, and it is bad... but we can limit the task to only am lets say, only 12 hour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22985/discussion-between-vividd-and-celtschk).

Comment: For some reason, login to the chat doesn't currently seem to work, despite the test page giving OK for all tests.

Comment: i think the solution is 284 lol @celtschk

Comment: And why do you think that?

Comment: thats because those 10=11-1 overlaps will not happen at the same moment as moments of possible hands inversion

Comment: When the hands are on the same position, you can certainly exchange them. Indeed, any solution must be a multiple of $11$ because rotating a valid hands position by $1/11$ of the full circle gives a valid hands position again. $284$ is not a multiple of $11$.

Comment: there will be 143 solutions to t=144t mod 1, but one of them is midnight/noon, so it will be 142, or 284 for wholef day

Comment: Anyway, I got login to chat working, so maybe we should continue there.

Comment: (Follow your previous link; I don't know if the "automatically move" would make a new room)

Comment: @celtschk , Would you like to enter the answer?

Comment: Done (I actually started with it before your latest comment, but due to being detailed, and thinking a lot about the validity of every single step, it took me quite some time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's slightly generalize the problem by considering clocks where the hour hand makes one round in $n$ hours (for our normal clocks we have $n=12$; however e.g. for [this clock](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Camara_Municipal_de_Barcelos_03.JPG) you have $n=24$).

Let's measure the time in hours. The minute hand makes one cycle every hour, so it gives the position modulo $1$; that is, the minute hand at times $t_1$ and $t_2$ is in the same position if and only if
$$t_1 \equiv t_2\ (\mod 1) \tag 1$$
On the other hand, the hour hand makes one cycle every $n$ hours, that is, the hour hand at times $t_1$ and $t_2$ is in the same position if and only if
$$t_1 \equiv t_2\ (\mod n) \tag 2$$
To avoid dealing with different mods, we can scale equation $(1)$ to also be modulo $n$:
$$nt_1 \equiv nt_2\ (\mod n) \tag{1a}$$
We can see that this rescaling is allowed by going back to the definition of the modulo operation: $x \equiv y\ (mod m)$ means there exists an integer $k$ so that $x=y+km$. Obviously we can multiply that equation with an arbitrary factor $s$ without changing its validity; thus we get $(sx) = (sy)+k(sm)$, or $sx\equiv sy\ (\mod sm)$.

Note that consistently calculating modulo $n$ nicely reflects the fact that after $n$ hours both hands are again in the same position.

Now two times $t_1$, $t_2$ are indistinguishable is the following two conditions are fulfilled:

- At time $t_2$ the hands are exactly reversed from time $t_1$, that is,
  $$\begin{align}
      nt_1 \equiv t_2\ (\mod n) \tag 3\\
      nt_2 \equiv t_1\ (\mod n) \tag 4
      \end{align}$$
  Equation $(3)$ says that the minute hand at time $t_1$ points in the same direction as the hour hand at time $t_2$, and equation $(4)$ the same with the two times exchanged. Note that, unlike in the integer case, we cannot replace $nt_k$ with $0$ in the modulo equation.
- The two times to distinguish are not the same,
  $$t_1 \not\equiv t_2\ (\mod n) \tag 5$$

Now to proceed, we would like to multiply both sides of $(4)$ with $n$ *without* adjusting the modulo part. However, may we do that? Let's go back to the definition: Equation $(4)$ says there exists an integer $k$ such that $nt_2 = t_2 + kn$. The new equation would say that there exists an integer $k'$ such that $n^2t_2 = nt_1 + k'n$. Obviously if $k$ is the integer solving the first equation, then $k'=nk$ is an integer (because $n$ is) and solves the second equation, so whenever the second condition holds, also the first does. However the reverse i *not* true; we might get additional solutions, so we need to check for that afterwards. This is similar to squaring both sides of an ordinary equation, where you also may get additional solutions which you might want to get rid of afterwards.

So let's do the transformation, and keep in mind that we will have to check equation (4) again for any solution we may find using the new equation. We thus have:
$$n^2t_2 \equiv nt_1\ (\mod n) \tag 6$$
From (3) and (6) we therefore get the condition for $t_2$
$$n^2t_2 \equiv t_2\ (\mod n)$$
or after bringing everything on the same side:
$$(n^2t_2 - 1)t_2 \equiv 0\ (\mod n)$$
The latter says that $(n^2-1)t_2$ must be a multiple of $n$, or
$$t_2 = \frac{nk}{n^2-1},\quad k\in\mathbb Z \tag 7$$
Now for $k=n^2-1$, we get $t_2=n$, which is equivalent to $t_2=0$, therefore this gives $n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$ different solutions for equation $(7)$.

From exchange symmetry between $t_1$ and $t_2$, we also get
$$t_1 = \frac{nk'}{n^2-1},\quad k'\in\mathbb Z \tag 8$$

However we might have too many solutions since we used non-equivalent transformations; therefore we have to check which of the solutions solve equations $(3)$ and $(4)$.

Inserting $(7)$ and $(8)$ into $(3)$ and $(4)$ gives
$$\begin{align}
\frac{n^2k}{n^2-1} &\equiv \frac{nk'}{n^2-1}\ (\mod n) \tag 9\\
\frac{n^2k'}{n^2-1} &\equiv \frac{nk}{n^2-1}\ (\mod n) \tag {10}
\end{align}$$
To simplify those relations, we rescale again, this time with the factor $(n^2-1)/n$, so the equations get modulo $n^2-1$:
$$\begin{align}
nk &\equiv k'\ (\mod n^2-1) \tag {11}\\
nk' &\equiv k\ (\mod n^2-1) \tag {12}
\end{align}$$
Note that $(11)$ and $(12)$ are now integer modulo equations; since further $n$ and $n^2-1$ are relatively prime, this time multiplying both sides of $(11)$ by $n$ is an equivalence relation; furthermore, obviously $n^2\equiv 1\ (\mod n^2-1)$. Therefore equations $(11)$ and $(12)$ are equivalent, and thus all values of $k$ indeed give valid solutions.

However we have to still check equation $(5)$. Remember that $(12)$ means that for some $m\in\mathbb Z$ we have $nk' = k + (n^2-1)m$.

Inserting $t_1$ and $t_2$, we get the condition
$$\frac{nk}{n^2-1} \equiv \frac{k+(n^2-1)m}{n^2-1}\ (\mod n)$$
which we can again rescale to
$$nk \equiv k+(n^2-1)m\ (\mod n(n^2-1))$$
and then rewrite into
$$(n-1)k \equiv (n+1)(n-1)m\ (\mod n(n+1)(n-1))$$
or after rescaling again
$$k \equiv (n+1)m\ (\mod n(n+1))$$
which means there exists an $m'$ so that $k = (n+1)m + n(n+1)m' = (n+1)m''$.
So equation $(5)$ is fulfilled whenever $k$ is an integer multiple of $n+1$. This happens $(n^2-1)/(n+1) = (n-1)$ times.

Therefore per round trip of the hour hand, that is per $n$ hours, there are $(n^2-1)-(n-1) = n(n-1)$ moments where you cannot tell the current time from the indistinguishable hands.

For the normal clock, $n=12$ and therefore there are $12\cdot 11=132$ such moments per $12$ hours, or $264$ moments per day.

For a 24h clock, $n=24$, and therefore there would be $552$ such moments.

Answer (score 2):

Let's measure time in units of $12$ hours, measure angles as a fraction of $2\pi$ and consider a period from midnight to noon.  Time will run from $0$ to $1$.  The hour hand position is $t$.  The minute hand position is $12 t \pmod 1$, the fractional part of $12t$  The times when you can't tell the time is when you can interchange the hands and get a legal time.  This would be when you consider the minute hand to be the hour hand, the hand you think is the hour hand, which is at $12t \pmod 1$ and the hand you think is a minute hand is the hour hand, so $t=144t \pmod 1$.  Noon and midnight are solutions to this equation, but you know what time it is. There will be $143$ times between $0$ and $1$ where this is satisfied, so $286$ times per day.

Comment: There are in total 11 times in 12 hours where both hands are in the same position; in each of those exchanging them trivially gets the same time, but you know the exact time.

Comment: So, this should change 286, no?

Comment: $286$ is the number in the last line of the answer.

Comment: i meant what celtschk said should affect the result, it is not 286

Comment: Yes, it should affect the result. Assuming the $144$ is right (I'm still thinking about this one), it means you have to subtract $11$ instead of $1$ from it, giving $133$ times in $12$ hours, or $266$ times per day.

Comment: While I don't yet know the right solution, I'm now convinced that $144$ is wrong: Why? Well, it's obvious that (using the time scale of the answer) if $t$ is a solution, then $-t$ is also a solution (it just corresponds to the mirror image of the clock's face). Now there are exactly two times where $t\equiv -t (\mod 1)$, namely $t=0$ (midnight/noon) and $t=\frac12$ (6 o'clock). Now at 6 o'clock, there's no question which time it is, since if the minute hand points down, the hour hand must point in between two numbers, so it can't point at 12. OTOH midnight/noon *is* a solution, …

Comment: … which is the only one not doubled by the symmetry. Therefore the total number of times (before correction for the case of both hands being at the same position) must be odd; however $144$ is clearly an even number.

Comment: @celtschk it looks to me you are right

Comment: OK, I've found the problem; it's actually quite simple: The equation $t\equiv 144t\ (\mod 1)$ can be rewritten as $143t\equiv 0\ (\mod 1)$, therefore there are $143$ solutions *before* removing midnight. Therefore you will not be able to tell the time $143-11=132$ times per 12 hours, or $264$ times per day.

Comment: also, you can treat condition t\equiv 144t\ (\mod 1) as if the day is 144 hour day, and 143 times the hand will overlap, the same way they overlap 11 times for 12 hour day